# Python & Pandas: Unable to drop columns

Tags: python, pandas

Here is part of my data:

```
USAF,   NCDC,  Date,     HrMn, I, Type,  QCP,  Dir, Q, I, Spd,   Q, 
034820,99999,19490801,0000,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  5.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0100,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0200,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0300,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0400,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  6.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0500,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0600,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.2,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0700,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.2,1,
```

I try to drop the data, but it reports some column does not exist.

```
ipath= "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\科研风速数据资料\Marham\\marham.txt"
uipath = unicode(ipath , "utf8")
file2 = open(uipath)
df = pd.read_csv(uipath,header=0)
# I can drop USAF, but unable to drop NCDC, I, Q, 
df.drop(['USAF', 'NCDC'], 1,inplace=True)
df.describe()
```

The reports:

```
ValueError: labels ['NCDC'] not contained in axis
```

So what's wrong with my code? I used to use the `df.drop(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1,inplace=True)` quite well.

UPDATE:

```
df.columns.tolist()
['USAF',
 '   NCDC',
 '  Date',
 '     HrMn',
 ' I',
 ' Type',
 '  QCP',
 '  Dir',
 ' Q',
 ' I.1',
 ' Spd',
 '   Q',
 ' ']
```

Comment: Can you post output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: @tom, that's possible, but I don't know how to deal with it. In my previous experience with pandas, it will automatically turn the second `Q` into `Q.1` when reading the data. However, in my case, it failed to do it, and I don't know why. However, This it cannot `drop` `NCDC` either.

Comment: The default separator is a comma `','`  in `read_csv` so your spaces in your csv are now part of your column and data

Comment: add `skipinitialspace=True` to `read_csv()`

Comment: @EdChum, yeah, just find that after you suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default separator for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) is comma but your data contains spaces, this has introduced leading spaces in your header and data, if you pass `skipinitialspace=True` then it imports fine:

```
In [106]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""USAF,   NCDC,  Date,     HrMn, I, Type,  QCP,  Dir, Q, I, Spd,   Q, 
034820,99999,19490801,0000,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  5.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0100,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0200,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0300,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  4.6,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0400,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  6.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0500,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.7,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0600,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.2,1,
034820,99999,19490801,0700,4,  SAO,    ,270,1,N,  8.2,1,"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), skipinitialspace=True)
df

Out[106]:
    USAF   NCDC      Date  HrMn  I Type  QCP  Dir  Q I.1  Spd  Q.1  \
0  34820  99999  19490801     0  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  5.7    1   
1  34820  99999  19490801   100  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  4.6    1   
2  34820  99999  19490801   200  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  4.6    1   
3  34820  99999  19490801   300  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  4.6    1   
4  34820  99999  19490801   400  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  6.7    1   
5  34820  99999  19490801   500  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  8.7    1   
6  34820  99999  19490801   600  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  8.2    1   
7  34820  99999  19490801   700  4  SAO  NaN  270  1   N  8.2    1   

   Unnamed: 12  
0          NaN  
1          NaN  
2          NaN  
3          NaN  
4          NaN  
5          NaN  
6          NaN  
7          NaN
```

You can then drop your columns:

```
In [108]:
df.drop(['USAF', 'NCDC'], 1,inplace=True)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 11 columns):
Date           8 non-null int64
HrMn           8 non-null int64
I              8 non-null int64
Type           8 non-null object
QCP            0 non-null float64
Dir            8 non-null int64
Q              8 non-null int64
I.1            8 non-null object
Spd            8 non-null float64
Q.1            8 non-null int64
Unnamed: 12    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 768.0+ bytes
```